# How can I make invisible border or something else where sprite would be pop up from

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to make my sprite pop out and be able to hide back behind something again, but I don't know how to implement it. Any ideas please?

Comment: Looks like you need a sprite mask. But I don’t understand what effect you are trying to get exactly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sprite to be hidden behind an "invisible" object, like this:

[image: Example of sprite mask]

You'll want to use a [Sprite Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html).

If you want to hide your sprite behind another sprite, like this:

[image: 2D Sorting Example]

Just change its order in layer. For more information, read [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html) of the unity manual.

Comment: Thanks, already solved this. But thanks